# How to rewrite this H2 query using an unsupported feature

Tags: java, sql, jpa, h2

I have a JPA Entity

```
public class GenericRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDate localDate;

    private String category;

    private Double amount;
}
```

At the moment I have some code that generates a `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` that looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to generate this map using a query on a H2 database (the data is already in the DB). However, it seems that I'm using an unsupported feature (is it the '+' operator?):

[image]

How can I rewrite the query, so that it runs on H2 (but possibly with wide compatibility)?

**EDIT 1**

This is the working query:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, CAST( MONTH(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-' || CAST(YEAR(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS mi, SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM GENERIC_RECORD 
GROUP BY CATEGORY, CAST( MONTH(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-' || CAST(YEAR(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [**H2**](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) SQL database, the [string concatenation operator](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#operand) is `||`, not `+`.

Answer (score 0):

H2 supports it but you have to use it as sql server mode, Please check the below link.
http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

To use it, append ;MODE=MSSQLServer to the database URL. Example URL:
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer

See also: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#operand